# Pass 'this' object to component - Typescript / React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, oop, this

I'd like to call a public method from the **FirstComponent** in my **OtherComponent**. However, I'm seeing this error:

**"TypeError: firstCompObj.foo() is not a function"** when I click the "Submit" button. After doing some debugging, the firstCompObj isn't showing up as type FirstComponent, but as an empty object.

I know that technically "foo" is a method, not a function, but what is the difference, and is it possible to call this method from the OtherComponent? Can I pass an object like this using the "**this**" keyword?

"FirstComponent.tsx":

```
    export class FirstComponent: extends React.Component<{}, {}>  {
..
        public foo() {
          // do something
        }
    
      private _otherComonent = (): JSX.Element => {
        return (
          <Other firstComponentObj={this}  />
        );
      };
    }
```

"otherfile.tsx":

```
export const Other: Component = (firstCompObj: FirstComponent) => {
...
     <Button text='Submit' onClick={() => {firstCompObj.foo();}} />
...
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass the function as props?

Comment: the way that the first comment below suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a function that calls `foo()` rather than passing the whole `FirstComponent`.

`Other` isn't actually a component right now because it doesn't take a props object.  Lets make it accept the prop `doFoo` which is a function that requires no arguments and returns nothing.

```
interface OtherProps {
  doFoo: () => void;
}

export const Other: React.FC<OtherProps> = ({ doFoo }) => {
  return <button onClick={doFoo}>Submit</button>;
};
```

We we call `Other` in the `render` method of `FirstComponent`, we provide that `doFoo` prop.  It will be an anonymous function that calls `this.foo` on the `FirstComponent` instance.  The arrow `=>` binds the `this` context.

```
export class FirstComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  foo() {
    // do something
    console.log("called foo from FirstComponent");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>There might be some content here</p>
        <Other doFoo={() => this.foo()} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`FirstComponent` could easily be a function component instead of a class component, but I'm keeping it the way that you had it.